# How to obtain $N_{\mu, i} (\lambda)=c_n \text{vol} (Q_i) \lambda^{\frac{n}{2}}+o(\lambda^{\frac{n}{2}})$? - Weyl's law

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, spectral-theory

I am trying to prove the Weyl's asymptotic law for eigenvalues. In the document [Weyl's law](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/weyl_law.pdf) of p. $4$, I have managed to go up to the step $$\tilde{\nu_k} \leq \nu_k \leq \mu_k \leq \tilde{\mu}_k \implies N_{\tilde{\nu_k}}(\lambda) \leq N_{\nu_k}(\lambda) \leq N_{\mu_k}(\lambda) \leq N_{\tilde{\mu}_k}(\lambda).$$ Right after, it is indicated that $N_{\mu, i} (\lambda)=c_n \text{vol}(Q_i) \lambda^{\frac{n}{2}}+o(\lambda^{\frac{n}{2}})$. Does someone could explain to me how it is possible to find an explicit function for $N_{\mu, i} (\lambda)$?

Comment: It is not an explicit function, it is the first term of an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: You are right, but could you show me how to find this asymptotic expansion?

Comment: It comes from what you have done for rectangles, but for higher dimensions. The proof should be more or less the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to find an explicit function for $N$. (For example, $N$ is not even continuous.)

To prove the *asymptotic* expansion 
$$N(\lambda) = c_n|\Omega|\lambda^{n/2} + o(\lambda^{n/2})$$
for the Dirichlet counting function on a domain $\Omega$, the simplest way in bounded Euclidean domains --- and one that I assume you're to use, since you appear to have the inequality between Neumann and Dirichlet eigenvalues --- is to appeal to *Dirichlet-Neumann bracketing*.

This idea stems from Weyl's original papers (1911,1912) and is described very well in volume 1 of Courant-Hilbert, *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics*. The basic idea is to cover $\Omega$ with small $\epsilon$-cubes $\{\chi_j\}$. Denote by $N_*^D$ the Dirichlet eigenvalue counting function and $N_*^N$ the Neumann eigenvalue counting function for the domain $*$. Let $\mathcal{S} = \{\chi\ |\ \chi\subset\Omega\}$ and let $\mathcal{T} = \{\chi\ |\ \chi\cap\Omega\neq\emptyset\}$.

Then argue that as
$$ S = \bigcup_{\mathcal{S}} \chi \subset \Omega \subset \bigcup_{\mathcal{T}}\chi = T  $$
by Dirichlet monotonicity and by the inequality you give in the question above, we have the following inequalities among counting functions:
$$ N_S^D \leq N_\Omega^D \leq N_T^D \leq N_T^N $$

Next, use the fact that all the $\chi$ are isometric, Dirichlet monotonicity, and *Neumann monotonicity* to argue that the following holds:
$$ (\#\mathcal{S})N_\chi^D \leq N_\Omega^D \leq (\#\mathcal{T})N_\chi^N $$
(Here $\#$ denotes the cardinality operator.)

Finally, use the explicit upper bounds you already know for the Dirichlet and Neumann counting functions of cubes to produce explicit upper and lower bounds for $N_\Omega^D$. The last step is to choose how $\epsilon\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

(There is a bit of a subtlety here, for as $\epsilon\to 0$, the bounds at a *fixed* $\lambda$ becomes very, very bad. This is an expression of the uncertainty principle: When the wavelength is larger than the size of the square, you can't capture the eigenfunction anymore. However, by letting $\lambda\to\infty$ as the squares shrink, you are able to keep the eigenfunctions "in resolution," as it were, and this lets you prove the theorem.)

Comment: For the rectangle $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, I've computed $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{N(\lambda)}{\lambda}= \frac{A(D)}{4 \pi}$, where $A(D)$ is the area of the rectangle. Could you tell me why $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \frac{N(\lambda)}{\lambda}= \frac{A(D)}{4 \pi}$ is equivalent to $N(\lambda) = c_2|\ A(D)|\lambda + o(\lambda)$?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity $c_2 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$. If $N(\lambda)/\lambda \to c_2A(d)$ then $N(\lambda) = c_2A(D)\lambda + \mbox{stuff}$ where $\mbox{stuff}$ has the property $\mbox{stuff}/\lambda\to 0$, i.e., is of class $o(\lambda)$. To be more precise, unwind the $\epsilon$-definition of a limit.

Comment: In the document, it is just defined to be $\frac{1}{4 \pi}$, sorry

Comment: I have already seen that before, but I don't remember why $stuff=o(\lambda)$. Could you remember me where this is it come from?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity Start with the $\epsilon$-definition of a limit and work with it. Then if you don't understand, pinpoint where you got stuck and ask a new question. :)